# Installing a celling light with 2 black and 1 yellow wire

Tags: lighting, ceiling

I moved into this apartment and there were no ceiling lights just bare wires hanging from the ceiling socket.
Now i have this light i bought from Ikea which has 2 wires 1 blue (N) and 1 brown(L) and in my ceiling I have following wires:
White
green
yellow
and 2 blacks

white and green wires are just passing through the socket and they have no ends but the yellow and 2 blacks have bare ends.
I have attached pictures if someone can tell me which wires do i have to connect to my light.
Thanks

edit: sorry for not mentioning it before, I live in Dubai, UAE

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Where in the world are you located? P

Comment: Questions seeking help with home wiring should always include the country and state/province that the house is in. Building codes and wiring color standards vary by location. A good answer for one querent could be completely wrong or even dangerous for another living in a different place.

Comment: I am located in UAE, Dubai

Comment: Here's a straw-man guess:  The cable coming in from the top right is power, the bottom left is a switch loop.  The pendant is installed in line with the hots between the two cables, and the neutral just runs straight through.  The grounds are joined up, perhaps because provision was made for a fixture that needs a ground but the previous fixture didn't.  But, I have no idea what the extra yellow cable might be.  Test if there's 240V between the blacks with the light switch on, and 0V with the light switched off.   Then do more tests in hope of figuring out what's what.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, I figured it out. So the yellow is getting power when the switch is on and black was neutral and the other black was running down the junction line towards balcony light, i guess that is the neutral for that balcony light which is not working by the way but as i wasn’t sure I covered it up with an electric tape and plugged the yellow into L and black into N and the light is working perfectly.

Comment: @Moiz Instead of posting your answer as a comment, please post it down below in the "Answer" box, then click the check mark when the system lets you. That'll help others find the answer if they have a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a volt meter or a way to detect which of the lines have power?

In my area one of the blacks would be hot but having 3 wires is unusual.

a switched hot goes to the brown wire or L terminal.
The neutral goes to the blue or n terminal.

I would check with a meter to see where there is voltage.
black to black?
then voltage black to yellow?
Last the other black to yellow 0 volts?
I was giving an example as 3 wires would not be normal with 2 the same color if you could take some measurements it would be helpful.

I have seen black as the hot and neutral depending on country.
If you could describe the wires coming in the box I can’t make them out clearly which ones are together etc

No one has answered probably because there is not enough information.