# Wiring a new IKEA light into old ceiling junction

Tags: wiring, light-fixture

I moved into this apartment and there were no ceiling lights so I bought a standard ceiling lamp from IKEA but I am sure how to connect it.

I have 2 Black wires and 1 yellow wire and the light is connected to a 2 way switch one is near the main door and other one is in same area as the light.
The light i got from IKEA have just 2 wires (L) and (N).
I dont know which one is live or which one is neutral as I havent tested it.
I also want to mention that the building is not too old its like 10 years old and is in UAE, Dubai.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Vote to close as this is a duplicate https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221342/installing-a-celling-light-with-2-black-and-1-yellow-wire   If you want to bring your question to the top of the list edit it or add information. Re posts creates a duplicate and the duplicate question is normally closed.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Installing a celling light with 2 black and 1 yellow wire](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/221342/installing-a-celling-light-with-2-black-and-1-yellow-wire)

Answer (score 0):

What you show on the lamp is L for the switched supply and N for the neutral.

Is is possible to put the switch in the neutral line theoretically but that can put someone in danger as the lamp will always be live.

Get a multimeter and check out the connections, this is not an opportunity for guesswork.